# How to add "android" libary to ndk project on Android Studio 3.1.3?

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

I ran into this problem when writing a audio-related app:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Android_SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\workspace\AndroidAudioNDK\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86_64 --target native-lib}
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86_64\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\android-ndk-r15c\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=x86_64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/android-ndk-r15c/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/android-ndk-r15c/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/android-ndk-r15c/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++11 -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot C:/android-ndk-r15c/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86_64\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  -llog -lm "C:/android-ndk-r15c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86_64/libgnustl_static.a" && cd ."
D:\workspace\AndroidAudioNDK\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:35: error: undefined reference to 'AAssetManager_fromJava'
D:\workspace\AndroidAudioNDK\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:35: error: undefined reference to 'AAssetManager_open'
D:\workspace\AndroidAudioNDK\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:35: error: undefined reference to 'AAsset_openFileDescriptor'
D:\workspace\AndroidAudioNDK\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:44: error: undefined reference to 'AMediaExtractor_new'
...
```

And I found a solution to this problem: [adding the `android` lib to `LOCAL_LDLIBS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12552371/3427520), but **How** to do that in the latest android studio (3.1.3)? I have tried the other solutions under that answer but none of them works for me: the build error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOCAL_LDLIBS` is for ndk-build but you're using CMake. A good starting place would be [one of our samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-jni/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt) which shows you that you need to use `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: It is Android Studio that is using CMake, not me. I'm just confused by the settings.

Comment: [This document](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis) should be updated and linked [in the Android Studio configure CMake page](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake). How on earth could a newbie know the correct name of those built-in libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution!

In the CMakeList.txt here:
[image: CMakeList.txt]

Modify it to

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( native-lib SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

target_link_libraries( native-lib
                       android
                       log )
```

Then the error is gone.

Reference:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code
- https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake